# How to change element in layout dynamically based on position of recyclerview Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My data set have a element `userId`. I want to check if the position's `userId` is equal to `userId` of previous position,then a `TextView` set to `GONE`.

**What I tried so far in `onBindViewHolder`:**

```
final Item item = itemsArray.get(position);

if(position - 1 > -1){
   if(items.get(position-1).getUserId() == item.getUserId()) {
      holder.username.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   }
}
```

But end up,some of the item with same `userId` their `username` is `gone`,but some of them which `userId` is not same with the previous position's `userId` the `username` is `gone` too.

To make it clear,I attach some image to clearly show what I want.

**This is what I want:**

[image]

But end up,it become like below image,as you see `item` with different `userId`,the `username` also `gone.

[image]

So,my question is,how can I check the `userId` of previous item is same as `userId` of current position,so it wont end up to the second image I attached.

If have other solution please let me know as well.Thanks in advance.

Comment: is your userId is String type?

Comment: is `int` type bro

Comment: Try adding else condition logic for "holder.username"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
 final Item item = itemsArray.get(position);
 holder.username.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 if(position - 1 > -1){
   if(items.get(position-1).getUserId() == item.getUserId()) {
     holder.username.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }else{
     holder.username.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
}
```

As you are using RecyclerView so some view that's holder.username state is "GONE" is reused.

Comment: it works..can u update the answer?cause u haven't add the else logic in the answer

Comment: This code  will also work. check it. and if my answer is correct please accept it

Comment: it's same as I attached.

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong way scan holders in an adapter and later changes it.
You should prepare your data before you set data in the adapter. Change model of your data(for example, add field `boolean isShowName` to `Item` class)